# How to update django database models in MySQL?

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models, mysql-workbench

How to update database table in MySQL ?

For example, in my Django app, I have a database table named 'Category1' , and I want to rename it into "Category" only.

After I run `python manage.py makemigrations` and  `python manage.py migrate` , it doesn't show any errors but I can't see any changes in my MySQL Workbench.

How to do this ?

Comment: show us your model

Answer (score -1):

You can check if your migration has been applied with `python manage.py showmigrations`, you should even add the app name at the end of this command to retrieve only migration from said app: `python manage.py showmigrations app_name`

If it hasn't been applied you should use `python manage.py migrate app_name migration_number`. You replace the app_name by the name of your app and the migration_number by the 4 first digits of your migration's name.

If you change your models and then applied the associated mirgations you should have modifications in your database (that's the point of migrations).

When using `makemigrations` be careful, sometimes Django will understand a field being renamed as a deletion and a creation of field. In your migration you should find the method `Alter field` if not you should [modify](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/migration-operations/#alterfield) it by hand.